# Copy JPG to parent folder location and change name to parent folder.JPG

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of files which has a JPG in the one of the sub-folders, I would like to copy the JPG out to the parent folder location and rename it to (parent_folder_name.jpg). I got the first part done but can't seem to get the rename part to work. Sometimes there will be more then one JPG in the sub-folder but I would rather get this to work then worry about that later.

```
Current
300_Print/315_A1_Poster_NewYork_Oct21/Indesign/A1_Poster_841x594mm.indd
300_Print/315_A1_Poster_NewYork_Oct21/LR_JPG/A1_Poster_841x594mm_LR.jpg

Target
300_Print/315_A1_Poster_NewYork_Oct21
300_Print/315_A1_Poster_NewYork_Oct21.jpg
```

Here is my code which works for the first part:

```
for f in "$@"; do
cd "$f"
find . -type f -regex ".*\.jpg" -exec cp {} . \; done
```

Here is what I try but didn't work:

```
for f in "$@"; do
cd "$f"
find . -type f -regex ".*\.jpg" -exec cp {} "${d#DIR}.jpg" \; done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the array "$@" includes the top directory names such as "300_Print", would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in "$@"; do                               # loop over the directories
    if [[ -d $d ]]; then                        # make sure the directory exists
        while IFS= read -d "" -r f; do          # read outputs of `find` and assign `f` to the path
            name=${f:${#d}+1}                   # remove leading dirname such as "300_Print"
            name=${name%%/*}                    # remove substring following the parent_folder_name
            cp -p "$f" "$d/${name}.jpg"         # copy the jpg file as the new name
        done < <(find "$d" -type f -name "*.jpg" -print0)
                                                # find *.jpg files under "$d"
    fi
done
```

It the output looks good, drop `echo` before `mv` and run again.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If it works as expected and you feel comfortable with the answer, would you please accept it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer? BR.